# SpringBoot Application deployed on Weblogic - Hibernate logging

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, logging, weblogic12c

I have a `SpringBoot` application deployed on a `Weblogic 12.2` server.

When the application is starting I can see in the console something like

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.8.RELEASE)

2019-11-05 10:40:09.581  INFO 7660 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application on ...
```

and further

```
2019-11-05 10:40:10.982  INFO 7660 --- [ (self-tuning)'] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 15ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
nov. 05, 2019 10:40:12 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion                                                                
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.11.Final}                                                                            
<05-nov.-2019, 10:40:12,878 AM CET> <Info> <org.hibernate.Version> <BEA-000000> <HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.11.Final}>
```

If I'm running the same application outside of weblogic I have

```
2019-11-05 10:49:16.871  INFO 11688 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 32ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
2019-11-05 10:49:17.902  INFO 11688 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.11.Final}
```

It seems that all the org.hibernate don't have the same pattern.  But I don't understand why and how to change it.

I tried changing it through my `application.propreties` but it's not working.  Even with `logging.level.org.hibernate=off` there are no changes.

My `application.properties` contains

```
#debug=true
ds1.spring.datasource.jndi-name=...
ds2.spring.datasource.jndi-name=...
# Let Spring autodetect the different SQL Dialects of each datasource
spring.jpa.database=default
# Tells Hibernate to generate SQL's with exactly names as specified in @table or @column
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
# Show sql
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
# Show Parameters bindings
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=trace
# Show Extracted data
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor=TRACE
```

For `pom.xml` it is quite more cmplicated because it's a multi modules project and there are lot of things needed for my company.

Comment: Can you please share your pom.xml/gradle.build file and application.properties files?

Comment: I edited the post.  For the pom.xml which part you would like to see ?  The spring boot application is packaged in a war and then in an ear.

Comment: Are you using log4j2 as logging api? What's the jboss-logging version? I would like to logging related dependencies. Also, post your weblogic-application.xml file if possible.